# how to check if xml tag has id attribute using php

Tags: php, xml

```
$xml=new DOMDocument;
$xml->load("".$base_url."assets/EIM/xml/defaultChart.xml");
$module_names=$xml->getElementsByTagName("name");
$len_modules=$module_names->length;
$ctr_module=0;
$varKO="Tsk";
while($ctr_module<$len_modules){
    $reports=$module_names->item($ctr_module)->getElementsByTagName("report");
    $len_reports=$reports->length;
    $ctr_report=0;
    while($ctr_report<$len_reports){
        $dashboard_selected=$reports->attributes();
    if($dashboard_selected=="dashboard"){
        $varKO="Hello";
    }
        $ctr_report++;
    }
$ctr_module++;
}
```

the part $dashboard_selected=$reports->attributes(); is an error because it was an undefined method. how do i check its attributes id? thanks a lot.

Comment: if you did `$module_names->item($ctr_module)`, so why didn't you try `$reports->item($ctr_report)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reports variable will be a DOMNodeList object: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php

You want to get the first node:
`$node = $reports->item(0);`

That will give you a DOMNode object:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

That object will have an `attributes` property that will return a DOMNamedNodeMap that you can check to see if it contains your attribute string:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnamednodemap.php